# Redirect and reverse differences in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a question about what are differences of redirect and reverse. Does it have influence on performance. And someone could me explain the differences between these 3 examples of code? What is the purpose of them and how can I efficiently apply them.

```
if 'comment' in request.POST:
            form = CommentCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.comment_user = request.user
                comment.comment_item = Item.objects.get(id=pk)
                comment.save()
//1             return redirect('detail-page', pk=item.id)
//2             return redirect(reverse('detail-page', kwargs={'pk': item.id}))
//3             return reverse('detail-page')
```

(I can not add any argument to the third one that`s the only difference I noticed).

Answer (score 3):

The two are not the same for a number of reasons. The first one is that [**`reverse(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) returns a *string* that is a URL to visit that view. [**`redirect(…`)** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) on the other hand returns a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect). This object can be returned by the view, and will normally trigger the browser to visit the page specified in the HTTP response. `redirect(…)` has a special parameter `permanent=…` that will based on the value return a `HttpResponseRedirect` (if `permanent=False` which is the default), or `HttpResponsePermanentRedirect` for `permanent=True`.

Another difference is that the `reverse(…)` works with `args=…` and `kwargs=…` parameters to fill in the values for the URL patterns. This is different for `redirect(…)` where one passes the positional and named parameters just as positional and named parameters. This thus means that if you do a `reverse('some_view', args=(some_parameter,), kwargs={'name': other_parameter})`, you obtain a HTTP response that points to that URL with `redirect('some_view', some_parameter, name=other_parameter)`.

A `redirect(…)` does not per se works on a view name. Indeed, if you pass a URL to the `redirect(…)` function, like `redirect('/foo/bar/qux/')`, it will construct a `HttpResponseRedirect` that redirects to the URL `/foo/bar/qux`. This is different for `reverse(…)` that only constructs URLs based on the name of the view, and its parameters.

Finally `redirect(…)` also accepts a model object that has a [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) will result in a `HttpResponseRedirect` that redirects to the URL constructed by that `.get_absolute_url()` method.

Your first (`//1`) and second (`//2`) line will thus produce the same result: a `HttpResponseRedirect` that redirects to the same URL, whereas the last one (`//3`) will return a string that contains a URL to the `detail-page` view.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect 1 and 2 are equivalent. I would assume 3 doesn't work as it's missing the ?required? product id?